# как добавить сервис для автоматического запуска в безопасном режиме windows 10

Tags: windows

Необходимо добавить прогу для автоматического запуска в безопасном режиме. работать в регедите по следующему пути:

\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal/Network

что необходимо туда добавить? можно подробный ответ?

upd:

необходимо добавить в автозагрузку в безопасном режиме сервис (находится по следующему пути):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ ***serviceName**

upd2:

Проблему решил. Добавил в SafeBoot\Minimal/Network папки с именем сервиса и задал параметр "Service" в колонке "data"

*Комментарии

**Akina:** *Раздел с указанием имени (CLSID либо имя соотв. раздела) и типа*

как найти CLSID необходимого мне сервиса?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *что необходимо туда добавить?* Раздел с указанием имени (CLSID либо имя соотв. раздела) и типа. Это ссылка на загружаемую службу или группу служб (см. HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services) и указание типа загрузки. В самой службе (простое приложение - не пойдёт) следует обеспечить выгрузку без выполнения функции при обычном режиме загрузки.